# actionbar up button, extend click area when no title or icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, up-button

My actionbar does not use an icon or a title, this makes the click area of the "up" button very small. How can I have a larger click area without a title and icon in the actionbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an image where the app icon would be. Just make a transparent image to the width and height for each drawable size you need and put it in the drawable folder, call the image logo (@drawable/logo). You then need to tell the activity to use the logo, it's not hard and these links should help.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#logo

Comment: the logo can be any width? I just assumed it would be transformed into a square. What about blank text in the title? "        " , maybe &nbsp; in HTML.text

Comment: No  I don't think so, what i meant was the width and height for each drawable size. The &nbsp; solution could work though, try \u00A0 as well, thats the Unicode no-break space character and I think that should work.

Comment: I did the blank text with multiple "\u00A0" instead, but I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to set a custom icon for the "up" button in your app theme as so:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
```